# Runtime MQ and Java version mismatch issue

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have my Java code compiled in jdk 1.6.

I am using MQ jar files (From MQ version 8.0) in my project build path.

My application server runs with jdk 1.6.

MQ version 8.0 installed in the server.

Now when I have deployed my application in the server, I am getting errors like :

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError" and errors related to major
>   version 50, 51 etc.

I understand the concepts of the version here, but I am little confused as why in the runtime there is a version mismatch happening as in the classpath it is referring to the same JAR files as during the project build. Is it due to the fact that MQ jars has been compiled in 51 which is of a higher version than 50 ? Please advise what can be done here.

Comment: if it says 51, at least one of your dependencies is compiled with Java 7. Java might be backwards compatible, it's not forwards compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JoshMc has been absolutely correct with the explanations of version mismatch of java and mq jars and all.

I would like to add that though I could understand the error when it occurred by seeing the mismatch between 51 and 50, but my issue was to somehow connect to MQ and make the application running without changing the existing installations. That's why I could not upgrade my java to JDK 1.7.

However I solved my problem by using old MQ 7 jars in the classpath for Weblogic Server. Because as my application behaves like a client there won't be any problem while connecting to the MQ server which has version 8 using MQ jars which has been built with java 6. So I have just copied old MQ 7 jars in a folder and used that path in my Weblogic CLASSPATH reference and that solved my problem.

Comment: Couple of points on the solution.  All versions of IBM MQ less than 8 are end of support from IBM (7.5 being the last as of April 30th 2018), so unless your client has an extended support contract they would have a hard time getting support via the PMR process for any MQ jar or MQ queue manager problems relating to apps using the old jars.

Comment: The other comment is that prior to MQ v8 IBM did not support moving the jar files out of the installed location (ex /opt/mqm/java/lib), as of v8 this is supported.  With MQ 7.5 what was supported for application servers such as Weblogic was the Resource Adapter (packaged as a rar), although you would still have the same support issues noted in my other comment.  Weblogic should be able to support installing a JMS provider as a RA using a rar.

Comment: Download link for 7.5.0.9 RA: [Fix Central -> 7.5.0.9-WS-MQ-Java-InstallRA](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~WebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere+MQ&release=7.5.0.9&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=*Java-InstallRA&useReleaseAsTarget=true&includeSupersedes=0&source=fc)

Answer (score 2):

To use the jar files that come with IBM MQ v8 and later you must be at Java 7 or later.  IBM Documents that from MQ v8 and later that the IBM MQ classes for Java and JMS are built with Java 7.  Oracle documents that classes built with Java 7 cannot be used with Java 6.  See below for references:

- In the MQ v8.0 KC page: [IBM MQ 8.0.0>IBM MQ>Product overview>What's changed in IBM MQ Version 8.0.0>Java: changes for Java 7](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q123560_.htm)

  > **The IBM MQ classes for Java and IBM MQ classes for JMS are now built
  >   with Java 7.**
  >
  > The Java 7 runtime environment supports running earlier class file
  >   versions.
- In the MQ v9.0 KC page: [IBM MQ 9.0.x>IBM MQ>Technical overview>IBM MQ Java language interfaces](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q123780_.html)

  > **From IBM MQ Version 8.0, the IBM MQ classes for Java and IBM MQ classes for 
  >   JMS are built with Java 7.** The Java 7 runtime
  >   environment supports running earlier class file versions.
- Oracle documents that Java 7 class files cannot be used with Java 6 in the following page:
  [Oracle Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility -> Binary Compatibility](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#binary) states the following:

  > **The class file version for Java SE 7 is 51**, as per the JVM
  >   Specification, because of the invokedynamic byte code introduced by
  >   JSR 292. **Version 51 class files produced by the Java SE 7 compiler
  >   cannot be used in Java SE 6.**

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct in your explanation with the version mismatch, however as I had my limitations I was not able to upgrade the Java version to 1.7. I had to find a way out for the issue keeping the existing setups intact. So I have just used old MQ 7 jars in my weblogic classpath while connecting to the MQ server (with version 8) and that actually solved my problem.
Thanks a lot for your time. Happy coding !!!